# Delphi linux database path

Tags: delphi

I am using WebBroker to write some APIs for a project that I am doing. I have added a DataModule and it contains a `TFDConnection` so that I can connect to a sqlite datadase. I have a project under windows (just as test) and it's saving the database on `D:\`.

On linux I was going to call `TPath.GetHomePath` but I don't think this is a good choice. Is there a way to put the database in the same folder as the project on Linux?

```
procedure TDataModule1.fdConnectionBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin

 if isLinux then
  begin
   fdConnection.Params.Values['Database'] := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, 'mydatabase.sqlite');
  end;

end;

procedure TDataModule1.fdConnectionAfterConnect(Sender: TObject);
const
  sCreateTableSQL = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...';
begin

  if isLinux then
   fdConnection.ExecSQL(sCreateTableSQL);

end;

function TDataModule1.isLinux: boolean;
begin
 Result := (TOSVersion.Platform = pfLinux);
end;
```

I plan to run an apache webbroker module on linux. I want the databse to be in the same folder as the linux executable, how can I do it? I see that `TPath` has the `GetHomePath` which works on Linux but other functions aren't supported.

Comment: Note, that not all machines have two drives (`D:\` is not a good place either). Try to store your database in an application data folder.

Comment: @Victoria my computer has D:\ and I am going to test here! The real stuff will run only on linux, so I wanted to find a way to store somewhere the database :)

Comment: I know that not every computer has D:\ so I wanted to use TPath; it can (I hope) give me the correct path to a proper folder somewhere

Comment: I haven't used the Linux version yet, but I suppose ParamStr(0) also works on Linux. As an aside... putting the database in the same folder as the executable is not a good (nor standard) idea, on any platform.